# Finding the angle between two functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, inner-products

I know that $\cos(\theta) = \frac{\langle f,g \rangle}{\|f\| \|g\|}$ for two functions $f$ and $g$. So, for two functions $x^n$ and $x^m$, $n \neq m$, on the interval $[-1,1]$ I want to find the angle between the two functions. Setting this up, I believe it would be

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{\int_{-1}^1x^nx^m\,dx}{(\int_{-1}^1|x^n|\,dx)(\int_{-1}^1|x^m|\,dx)}$$

Evaluating this, I seem to get a mess of

$$\cos(\theta) = \frac{(1 + (-1)^{n+m})(n+1)(m+1)}{4n+4m+4}$$

which doesn't feel right. Am I overlooking something simple about this?

Comment: What kind of answer were you expecting? How simple did you think the answer would be? But your proposed answer is missing a parenthesis, and looks like it will exceed 1 if $m$ and $n$ are large enough.

Comment: $||f||_2=\sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}=\left(\int_{-1}^1|f(t)|^2dt\right)^{1/2}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson Based off of the way the initial problem was phrased, I was expecting a trivial solution. However, if that's not the case then I feel better about my solution. And yes, I did forget a parenthesis, I will fix that.

Comment: @Bumblebee Yeah that would probably explain my issues. Can't believe I messed that up. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that $\|f\|\|g\|,$ coded as \|f\|\|g\|, looks different from $||f|| ||g||,$ coded as ||f|| ||g||. I edited accordingly. $$ \begin{align} & \|f\|\|g\| \\ \\ & ||f|| ||g|| \\ \\ {} \end{align} $$

Comment: @Bumblebee : $\quad \uparrow \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the inner product is $\displaystyle \langle f,g\rangle = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) g(x)\, dx$ then $\displaystyle \|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle} = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 f(x)^2\, dx},$ so
\begin{align}
\cos\theta = {} & \frac{\langle x^n, x^m\rangle}{\|x^n\|\|x^m\|} = \frac{\int_{-1}^1 x^{n+m} \,dx}{\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 (x^n)^2\,dx \int_{-1}^1 (x^m)^2\, dx}} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{2/(n+m+1)}{\sqrt{(2/(2n+1)) (2/(2m+1))}} \text{ if } n,m \text{ have the same parity} \\
& \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \text{and 0 if they have opposite parities} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2m+1)}}{n+m+1} 
\end{align}